# How can i query something specific out of this nested JSON type column in Bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have a column called context: see below
[image: I have a column called context: see below]

And I want to query out the highlighted part -**7efdfa8e2df075bd**

I am using this and it isn't working. **JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(context,'$.id')**  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is positioned inside `device`.

Try `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(context,'$.device.id')`

Comment: adding an explanation can be helpful